# Where to use binary Binary Cross-Entropy Loss

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, loss-function

I have 2 questions:

1. is there any source where I can see TensorFlow's implementation of those loss functions? I have searched it on Github, on their website and haven't found formulas according to which those loss functions are implemented.
2. when I use tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True), loss function, what should be target? one hot vector([[0,1]]) or just constant tensor ([1]) ? I observed and noticed that it works on both of them. can you write down the formula?

edit: I have classification such as cats vs dogs.

Comment: Your loss function depend on the problem and you target type continuous or discrete values and and if its binary or multi class , BinaryCrossentropy its for binary classfication and you can just google the formula

Comment: Here is a quite good explanation for begginers: 
https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-binary-cross-entropy-log-loss-a-visual-explanation-a3ac6025181a

Comment: @Yefet i know but tf sometimes changes the original formula and that is why i needed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `y_true` and `y_pred` should be tensors like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

binary_crossentropy = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy()

a = tf.convert_to_tensor([1., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0.])
b = tf.convert_to_tensor([.1, .9, 2., 8., 4., 3.])

binary_crossentropy(a, b)
```

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=8.067944>
```

`from_logits` should be `True` if you have no activation function on your final layer. It also work if bot are one-hot encoded:

```
d = tf.convert_to_tensor([[.4, .6], [.8, .2], [.7, .3], [.1, .9], [.2, .8], [.4, .6]])
c = tf.convert_to_tensor([[.8, .2], [.3, .7], [.4, .6], [.9, .1], [.2, .8], [.7, .3]])

binary_crossentropy(c, d)
```

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=1.0452858>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You should check out the official Tensorflow API documentation: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/binary_crossentropy. At the top of the page you can find a link "View source on GitHub". This loss refers to the Keras backend implementation to binary crossentropy: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/b36436b087bd8e8701ef51718179037cccdfc26e/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py#L4795
2. Also from the documentation: "Use this cross-entropy loss when there are only two label classes (assumed to be 0 and 1). **For each example, there should be a single floating-point value per prediction.**"

Comment: y_true = [[0, 1], [0, 0]]
y_pred = [[0.6, 0.4], [0.4, 0.6]]  yes but what are these? i copyed them from official tutorial, i have same data. [0,1]=cat    [1,0]=dog. i trained model and it learns(i tested it). i have 2 units on last output layer without activation

Comment: @DatoNefaridze, yes it seems that you can just give one-hot encoded vectors as well. Good reflex to check the source code as in this example, the documentation does not cover all cases!